# Representing a text file as single unit in Java, and matching strings in the text

Tags: java, string-matching, textmatching

How can I have a text file (or XML file) represented as a whole string, and search for (or match) a particular string in it?

I have created a BufferedReader object:

```
BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
```

and then I have tried to use the Scanner class with its option to specify different delimiters, like this:

```
//Scanner scantext = new Scanner(input);
//Scanner scantext = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("");
Scanner scantext = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\n");
while (scantext.hasNext()) {  ... }
```

Using the Scanner class like this I can either read the text line by line, or word by word, but it doesn't help me, because sometimes in the text, which I want to process, I have

```
</review><review>
```

and I would like to say: if you find "`<review>`" anywhere in the text, do something with the following next lines (or piece of text) until you find "`</review>`". The problem is that `<review>` and `</review>` are on different places in the text, and sometimes glued to other text (therefore the empty space as delimiter doesn't help me).

I have thought that I might use the regular expression API in Java (the Pattern and Matcher classes), but they seem to match a particular string or line, and I want to have the text as one continuous string (at least this was my impressions from what I have read about them). Could you tell me what structures/methods/classes I should use in this case? Thank you.

Comment: I have edit the text several times after posting it, so everything is read now, I hope (sorry for the non-seeable things)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to parse XML with regular expressions; it leads only to pain. There are a lot of <strike>very nice</strike> [existing](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html) [XML](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html) [APIs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) in Java already; why try to reinvent them?

Anyway, to search for a string in a text file, you should:

1. Load the file as a string ([example](http://www.coderanch.com/t/403914/Java-General-beginner/java/do-read-entire-file-all))
2. Create a [`Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to search for
3. Use a [`Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to iterate through any matches

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though you are trying to work with a structured xml file, and would suggest that you look into [javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) or other built in [APIs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) to parse the document.

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML parser.

Or use xpath, like in this [example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html).

Answer (score 1):

> I have thought that I might use the regular expression API in Java (the Pattern and Matcher classes), but they seem to match a particular string or line, and I want to have the text as one continuous string

Um, does something prevent you from reading the XML file into a String, and then operating on that, using the regular expression API?

You can easily read a file into a String using e.g. [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from Apache [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/): see [`readFileToString(File file, String encoding)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

I also would recommend using a XML parsing API...But as you only want to do something in case of "review" tag, maybe you could use SAX better than DOM...

Answer (score 0):

I think here, we can copy individual line in the text file into a string and then try to match a substring(search string) with the string(line)

But error produces while excuting metacharacters like / or # etc..